# Clients behind proxy can not connect to websocket server end point running on weblogic server .How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, proxy, weblogic, java-websocket

I have web socket server written in JAVA EE 7 and client in HTML and javascript .I am running on weblogic server. All clients on my local machine are able to connect to the server and send messages but the remote clients in the same network are not able to connect to the server.I am behind a proxy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcp connection establishes successfully, isn't it? or inbound/outbound rules can block connection. You can check firewall setup if exists. Other clients in same domain with you ? Are there any configuration,rule for 80/443 ports.